# Finding N in binomial question

Tags: probability, statistics

A normal die with probability 1/6.

Question
The number of times you have to throw a cubic die so that we have 80percent change of getting at least one 1.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $X$ the rv that counts how many times "1 is drawn", say $X\sim Bin(n;\frac{1}{6})$

the probability you are looking for is

$$\mathbb{P}[X=0]\leq 0.2$$

$$\Bigg(\frac{5}{6}\Bigg)^n\leq 0.2$$

$$n\geq 9$$